# How to load data and function from dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to run a Monte Carlo simulation with many parameters and i would like to load the assumed distribution and values directly from a table.

Imagine to store data in this format on a table (in this case i just use a single vector for simplicity)

```
set.seed(0)
a <- c("rnorm", 2, 0.1)
```

Then I would like to load not only the value, but also th type of distribution (rnorm, rtriangle, etc..). I am not clear how to make R load the "rnorm" text and understand it as a function command

```
nsim <- 100
simul <- a[1](nsim, a[2], a[3])
```

Thank you!

I tried to run the script but i cannot find a way to load a function command from a vector / table

Comment: All elements of a vector will be coerced to the same type, so your current code won’t work anyway. But if you use a *list* instead of a vector it will work, and you can store the function *directly* (rather than via a string); i.e. `a = list(rnorm, 2, 0.1)` will work and is pretty standard R. Remember to use `[[…]]` instead of `[…]` to access list elements. For readability it would be better to use a named list, however.

Comment: This is a good response - why not make it an answer instead of a comment?

Comment: re: Konrad's comment: if you insisted on keeping it as a character vector, you'd have to do something like `get(a[1])(as.numeric(a[2]), as.numeric(a[3]))`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Konrad and Mark for the answers, that I post below.
The first solution is by using a list based on Konrad's input:

```
nsim <- 100
a = list(funct, m, s) 
simul <- a[func[1]](nsim, a[[2]], a[[3]])
```

The second solution ( which would suits my case better since  want to load a long list of distributions from an excel) is:

```
nsim <- 100
a <- data.frame(c("rnorm","runif"),c(2,1), c(0.1,3))
par1 <-get(a[1,1])(nsim,as.numeric(a[1,2]), as.numeric(a[1,3]))
par2 <-get(a[2,1])(nsim,as.numeric(a[2,2]), as.numeric(a[2,3]))
```